# Heroku pictures

Tags: image, ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, heroku

I'm trying to get my pictures to upload on Heroku and have been unsuccessful. I have changed the

```
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

to

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

I have also looked through the Heroku manual  and it is very unclear about this issue at least to me.

Does anyone have an idea how to get it to work?

I appreciate the help

Comment: rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is the wrong place to store you uploaded images they recomend using a system like [Cloudinary](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudinary) that stores the images in the AWS (Amazon Web Services).

Ryan Bates has a really good video on how to upload images as well [Carrierwave file uploads](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)